# How to use a variable as an attribute in python

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I wanted to write a Python script to bruteforce hashes that permits the user to insert the hashing algorithm as a string (Result: `algorithm = "md5"`), but when I tried to use it like this in the hashlib library: `guess_hash = hashlib.algorithm(bytes(guess)).hexdigest()`, it obviously gave me this error: `AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute 'algorithm'`
So I did a quick research and I tried using getattr like this: `getattr(hashlib,guess(bytes(guess1))).hexdigest()` (probably really wrong) and it gave me this error: `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`.
What should I do? Thanks in advance and sorry for the noobiness :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's actually `bytes` complaining (which it will with Python 3 but not Python 2). It would appear that you've also swapped the meanings of `algorithm` and `guess` in your `getattr`, and you'll want to do something like

```
getattr(hashlib, algorithm)(bytes(guess, 'utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed passing the actual algorithm name to the `getattr` call.

Try this:

```
getattr(hashlib, 'md5')(bytes(guess)).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple is better than complex. You can just have a bunch of if statements and do the correct call in those. If there are too many, you could use a hashmap where the key is a string and the value a function.

`getattr` is, however, the correct call to fetch an attribute with a variable, but the error tells you that you cannot convert a string to a bytestring without specifying the encoding. The `bytes` function allows you to specify encoding like this:

```
a_byte_string = bytes(a_regular_string, encoding='utf8')
```